# iOS Undo the deleted cells in my tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my project i just want to hide the cells when swipe happend. if i hide the cell from tableview undo button will generate top of my navigation bar. Click on undo button the hidden cells should reappear.

Here is my code..

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    Download *download = [self.downloadManager.downloads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Get path to documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Get zip file from path..

    NSString *fileInDocumentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:download.name];

    NSLog(@"Looking for zip file %@", fileInDocumentsPath);

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileInDocumentsPath])
    {
        UITableViewRowAction *HideAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Hide" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
            //insert your editAction here

            [self.downloadManager.downloads removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            [tableView endUpdates];

            UIBarButtonItem *UndoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Undo" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(UndoAction:)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=UndoButton;

        }];
        HideAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Delete"  handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
            //insert your deleteAction here



        }];
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return @[deleteAction,HideAction];

    }
    else
    {

        UITableViewRowAction *HideAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Hide" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
            //insert your editAction here
        }];
        HideAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        return @[HideAction];

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `NSUndoManager` for record action in undo stack and you can easily undo.

This [link](http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/) will help you to get more idea.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh. Will work on it and get back to u if any queries

Comment: most wel come @RajaSasidharan

Comment: Hi i tried but couldnt complete. is there any tutorial. Or ideas

Comment: I didnt get that..

Comment: @RajaSasidharan, Here are some links, Apple Developers [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/iPhoneUndo.html) and other [link](https://macdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/undoredo-in-a-cocoa-application-example-to-undoredo-addition-deletion-of-rows-in-a-table-view/). I think this links will help you.

Comment: oK it works cool.. thank you

Comment: please up my answer if my answer is helpful.

Comment: Sorry dude nsundomanager not working proper.. can you help.. i will upload my code..